# Why does an expression for a Javascript function that returns void still execute?

Tags: javascript

I'm so confused about how `Void` operator (in javascript) works and what is it's role. as i read, `Void` is an operator that evaluate an expression **without returning a value**, but by executing that script for example:

```
<html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>

  <a href="javascript:void(alert(1+1))">Click me!</a>

 </body>
</html>
```

After clicking on the link, the browser shows the value 2, which mustn't be shown since the evaluated expression (`alert(1+1)`) shouldn't return a value due to being an operand of the `Void` operator.
Can someone clear it up for me please?.

Comment: Your code is doing what you are telling it to. The `void` method says to ignore any returned value from the inner expression (e.g., `alert(1+1)` ). That doesn't stop it from being processed.

Comment: Right; specifying `void` as the return type only prevents something from being returned from the Javascript function; it doesn't prevent the `alert` expression from being evaluated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What is the 'something' in this situation?.

Comment: @Mehdi: Whatever the expression inside the function evaluates to (in this case, whatever `alert(1+1)` returns.

Comment: What `alert(1+1)` returns?, isn't 2?

Comment: [`Window.alert()` is a method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)  It doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return values and side effects are two different things. [`void` eliminates the return value, it has no effect on side effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

> This operator allows inserting expressions that produce side effects into places where an expression that evaluates to undefined is desired.

`alert()` produces a window as a side effect, not a return value. `1+1` is an expression that *does* return a value, but that return value is handled by `alert()`, not the `void` operator.

Note that `alert()` might not return a value normally, it does not in Firefox 47, making the `void` wrapper redundant in this particular case.